strange error from @here api autocomplete endpoint: Illegal input for parameter 'types'. Unsupported value: 'city'. Actual parameter value: 'city'
Unsure if this is just a bug in here's api or I'm doing something wrong. It seems to be intermittent so perhaps its a bug. I only want to return city/locality as suggestions to the user.
@here_maps-api-for-javascript.js?v=c70c6f7d:12146 Error: Illegal input for parameter 'types'. Unsupported value: 'city'. Actual parameter value: 'city'

I am calling it like this:
    function autocomplete(query) {
    const service = platform.getSearchService();

    return service.autosuggest({
        limit: 5,
        types: 'city',
        q: query,
        at: '41.48,-87.06', //must pass something
        lang: 'en-US',
    }, console.log, console.error)
}

